# Magento2 module not getting installed with git clone from local repo

Tags: magento2, module

I am trying to install a module `Abcd_Core` using the command

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

The output does list all the modules except `Abcd_Core`. Also the `app/etc/config.php` does not have `Abcd_Core` in the array.

Here is what I did..

---

The module is located at `<magento>/app/code/`

The file

## app/code/Abcd/Core/registration.php

has the code

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
     'Abcd_Core',
     __DIR__
 );
```

In `app/code/Abcd/Core/etc` folder I have `module.xml`, `di.xml` files and a folder `adminhtml`.

## module.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Abcd_Core" setup_version="1.0.0" />
 </config>
```

## di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Store\Model\Store" type="Abcd\Core\Model\Store" />
</config>
```

The `app/code/Abcd/Core/etc/adminhtml` folder has `routes.xml` and `system.xml`.

There is a file `app/code/Abcd/Core/Model/Store.php` which overrides the functionality of method `getBaseUrl()`.

---

I tried cleaning the cache and then running the setup:upgrade several times, also tried

```
sudo php bin/magento module:enable Abcd_Core
```

but unable to install/enable the module.

Can anyone provide some input on what needs to be corrected?

FYI, I cloned the files from a git repository in my organization.

Thank you,
Hari CL

Answer (score 0):

You also need a composer.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Abcd/Core",
  "description": "la",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {

  },
  "extra": {
    "map": [
      [
        "*",
        "Abcd/Core"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Also please clean everything in the var folder and flush the cache. If it still doesn't work, check the var/logs file.

Comment: Added composer.json with code{
  "name": "Abcd/Core",
  "description": "Abcd Core Module",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {

  },
  "extra": {
    "map": [
      [
        "*",
        "Abcd/Core"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Abcd\\Core\\": ""
    }
  }
}

Comment: Hi Claudiu, I added the composer.json but the issue persists. I tried to install the same module in a new Magento2 installation, and it worked. I think there should be some issue in the code added to the repository

Comment: @HariCL possibly, check the error logs. it should be something there. also use -v in command line for more messahges